# Protractor 3.3 firefox is very slow

Tags: performance, firefox, protractor

**USING:**

- currently latest Protractor 3.3.0
- Firefox is 45
- Mac OS X Yosemite

**ISSUE:**

So I've been trying to figure out when this slowness occurred. Pretty much everything is running very slow. I have a login page that used to take around 5 seconds now it's taking almost 3 times longer.

**WHAT I'VE TRIED**

I did find a setting that seemed to make things work like how I expected them to work for the login page but then it messes things up on other tests because it's not waiting long enough.

the only way i've been able to speed it up was the setting mentioned above

```
exports.config.capabilities.pageLoadingStrategy = "eager";
```

I have tried via browser stack on firefox 45 and on windows 7 and mac osx Yosemite but the problem seems to be there still. I also tried reverting to protractor 3.0 and 2.51 to see if that made a difference. I tried using older firefox browsers like 43 and 44. I can't seem to find much on the issue. I don't know if it's possible to somehow set the pageLoadingStrategy to eager and then once logged in back to normal? Any suggestions on how to speed up firefox are appreciated.

> Firefox takes almost 3 times longer than chrome.

**CHROME**

[image: CHROME]

**FIREFOX**

[image: FIREFOX]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are running `Chrome` with `directConnect` and `Firefox` without.

You can avoid starting up the selenium server and [run `Firefox` in `directConnect` too](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/server-setup.md#connecting-directly-to-browser-drivers):

> directConnect: true - Your test script communicates directly Chrome Driver or Firefox Driver, bypassing any Selenium Server.
>
> The advantage of directly connecting to browser drivers is that **your test scripts may start up and run faster**.

Comment: that is definitely a good tip to speed things up a little bit. but it still seems incredibly slower in comparison. And that slowness multiplies when using saucelabs. I was trying to work locally first to see if there was anything that could be done. I would like to see if there is anything else that can be done.

Answer (score 0):

If I use firefox directConnect: true. 
Then browser.action() is not working. It give error Http method not allowed

Comment: Is it the answer or just a comment?

Comment: you can use this:

config.capabilities = {
    browserName: "firefox",
    'moz:firefoxOptions': {
      args: ["--headless","--window-size=1920x1080"]
    }
  }


I think slow issue will fix